# How do I correctly use @PathVariable in Java+Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller that works fine for other request mappings, but I'm having trouble getting one to work with the `@PathVariable` annotation.

In [this example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) (see "URI Template Patterns") it has this example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/owners/{ownerId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String findOwner(@PathVariable String ownerId, Model model) {
    Owner owner = ownerService.findOwner(ownerId);
    model.addAttribute("owner", owner);
    return "displayOwner";
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping( value="/ViewReport/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView TestJson(final Model model){
    model.addAttribute("fnord", "{\"hello\":\"awesome\"}"); 
    return new ModelAndView("reportViewJson");  
}    

@RequestMapping( value="/ViewReport/jayson/{foobar}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView TestJayz(final Model model, @PathVariable String foobar){
    model.addAttribute("fnord", "{\"hello\":\""+foobar+"\"}");  
    return new ModelAndView("reportViewJson");  
}
```

Then I have a `web.xml` file containing this:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>autoreport</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ViewReport/jayson/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>autoreport</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ViewReport/json</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Now, when I navigate to `/ViewReport/json`, I get the JSON `{"hello": "awesome"}` as I would expect. However, when I navigate to `/ViewReport/jayson/42` I get

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
```

What am I doing wrong with my usage of the `PathVariable`, and what do I need to do to fix it?

### Update

When my server starts up it spits out these lines:

```
[ INFO] 14:15(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:registerHandler:315)
Mapped URL path [/ViewReport/json.*] onto handler 'reportViewController'

[DEBUG] 14:15(AbstractBeanFactory.java:doGetBean:246)
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'reportViewController'

[ INFO] 14:15(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:registerHandler:315)
Mapped URL path [/ViewReport/json/] onto handler 'reportViewController'

[DEBUG] 14:15(AbstractBeanFactory.java:doGetBean:246)
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'reportViewController'

[ INFO] 14:15(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:registerHandler:315)
Mapped URL path [/ViewReport/jayson/{foobar}] onto handler 'reportViewController'
```

And when I make the request I get this:

```
[DEBUG] 20:45(DispatcherServlet.java:doService:823)
DispatcherServlet with name 'autoreport' processing GET request for [/ViewReport/jayson/fnord]

[ WARN] 20:45(DispatcherServlet.java:noHandlerFound:1108)
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ViewReport/jayson/fnord] in DispatcherServlet with name 'autoreport'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring has magic; parameter order matters.
Try inverting the order of your handler parameters.
Instead of this:

```
public ModelAndView TestJayz(final Model model, @PathVariable String foobar)
```

Try this:

```
public ModelAndView TestJayz(@PathVariable String foobar, final Model model)
```

Take 2:

Try changing the mapping in your web.xml to something more generic.  For example:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>autoreport</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ViewReport/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I used `/spring/*` in my test web.xml, @RequestMapping("/blammy/{value}") in my controller, then sent the request to "{WEBROOT}/spring/blammy/testvalue" where "{WEBROOT}" was the web-root of my test app.

Comment: The only parameter order that matter in Spring is with `BindingResult` and there's a very good reason. Why would it matter here?

Comment: And sadly this didn't work. But I've added some more info - apparently it *is* mapping the path, but somehow it's not being directed correctly...

Answer (score 0):

request mappings a relative to the dispatcher servlet mapping (by default, see `alwaysUseFullPath` property in `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` for more information).

if you request a resource `/ViewReport/jayson/fnord` spring mvc is looking for a handler mapped to `fnord`.

you would need to request `/ViewReport/jayson/ViewReport/jayson/fnord`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **@PathVariable(value="foobar") String foobar** ?

```
@RequestMapping( value="/ViewReport/jayson/{foobar}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView TestJayz(final Model model, @PathVariable(value="foobar") String foobar){
    model.addAttribute("fnord", "{\"hello\":\""+foobar+"\"}");  
    return new ModelAndView("reportViewJson");  
}
```

Comment: I'll double check, but I'm fairly certain that I did.

Comment: Yep, and still no dice.